# Could not comapre two dates using PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to compare two given dates using PHP but as per my code its giving the wrong result. I am explaining my code below.

```
    $date=strtotime('18-05-2019 02:36 PM');
$stdate=date('d-m-Y H:i A',strtotime('18-05-2019'));
if($date==$stdate){
  echo 'same date';
}else{
  echo 'other date';

}
```

Here one date has `date and time` and other date has only date format. I need to compare the both dates using PHP. As per above code I am getting the result `Other date` which is wrong.

Comment: if you know the format will never change split the first one on space

Comment: When managing dates, I would recommend using the format `Y-m-d H:i:s` instead since it makes more logical sense. Your current format is pretty unclear at times. Example: `10-05-2019`, is that October 5 or May 10?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I updated as per you but same issue.

Comment: `$date` will contain a unix timestamp (numeric) while `$stdate` will be a date-string. Those two will never be equal. Just do strtotime() on both and compare the results. So your if-statement are actually comparing: `if (1558182960 == "18-05-2019 00:00 AM")` which will obviously never be equal.

Comment: @subhra So u need to compare date or date with time

Answer (score 1):

The date string '18-05-2019' is equivalent to '18-05-2019 00:00 AM'. When no time is given, it is usually just set as midnight. Hours and minutes are taken into account when using strtotime(). So your code is actually performing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Format the date with [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) before you compare the values. You can take the UNIX timestamp generated by [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and strip the time portion off:

```
$date=date( "Y-m-d", strtotime('18-05-2019 02:36 PM'));
$stdate=date( "Y-m-d", strtotime('18-05-2019'));

if($date==$stdate){
    echo 'same date';
}else{
    echo 'other date';
}
```

This has been tested and will echo 'same date'.

Comment: Why would you turn them into strings instead of using the timestamps?

Comment: @subhra It never pass without giving exact time for `stdate` this will give `other date` only

Comment: My thought it was either that or adding a fixed time to both dates. I suppose [`date_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) could work too, but it felt like extra steps to me.

Comment: OP wants to know if the dates are the same, but `strtotime()` produces "1558204560" and "1558152000" for the same date (the first with a time and the second defaulting to midnight).